# Google distance metrix api returns REQUEST_DENIED

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-places-api

I am using URLConnection to connect to the URL to get distance and time between two locations in android. Everytime it returns "REQUEST_DENIED". I have generated key without any restrictions and have enabled Google Maps Android API,  Google Maps Geocoding API and  Google Places API Web Service. Code snippet:

Response returned IS :
{
   "destination_addresses" : [],
   "error_message" : "This API project is not authorized to use this API.",
   "origin_addresses" : [],
   "rows" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}

```
URL mapUrl = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=Washington,DC&destinations=New+York+City,NY&key=My_Key");
URLConnection connection = mapUrl.openConnection();
InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isw);
String line = "";
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println(line);
}
```

Also note that sometimes results are shown in browser when I paste the same URL in browser. But not always. If it shows "REQUEST_Denter image description hereENIED" thereafter it always shows same. I tried to disable and enable the API services again. After enabling for the first time I got the results in browser but not through android app.
How can I resolve the issue? No of requests are also not the issue since it is within the limit.

Comment: Take a look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#distance_matrix_status_codes

Answer (score 0):

1. You need key exactly for [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start#get-a-key) (Google Maps Android API, Google Maps Geocoding API and Google Places API Web Service is not enough).
2. Seems there is a bug in Distance Matrix API: replace `New+York+City,NY` by `New+York,NY` in your request and everything should works fine:

   `URL mapUrl = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=Washington,DC&destinations=New+York,NY&key=My_Key");`

will response:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "New York, NY, USA" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Washington, DC, USA" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "225 mi",
                  "value" : 361954
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "3 hours 50 mins",
                  "value" : 13778
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```